# Count occurencies of managed metadata in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-rest-api

I have custom list with multi-select managed metadata column.
How could I count the number of items (preferably using rest api), which has particular metadata in this column?

For example on my list there are items like below:

```
Item1: keyword1, keyword2
Item2: keyword1, keyword4
Item3: keyword3
```

And now, if I search for "keyword1", I should get value 2 (because 2 items have this metadata). If I search for "keyword4", I should get value 1.

Comment: Do you want to count number of keywords in metadata column or number of items in a list?

Comment: Number of items in a list, which contains particular metadata.

Comment: If you only need to get the number of items, a simple approach for that would be just to create a new view, where you filter the `[Multi-select managed metadata column] = particular metadata`. Then you can get the number of items by enabling the Totals to the view.

Comment: @moe problem is that my "particular metadata" is dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a syntax to get the count from the search results as we don`t have a way to query to get the total count.

```
siteurl/_api/search/query?querytext='(owstaxId<<metadata field name>>:"<<keyword>>") (IsDocument:True) Path:"<<library path>>" ListID:"library guid"'&selectproperties='Title'&startrow=0&rowlimit=10&trimduplicates=false
```

The example as follows

```
https://tenant.sahrepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='(owstaxIdMarket:"HP+Spring+2017") (IsDocument:True) Path:"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/Setup Sheets" ListID:"74df6ac9-6c26-4c17-a6b3-60756cdae097"'&selectproperties='Title'&startrow=0&rowlimit=10&trimduplicates=false
```

Then you can get the "Total Rows" value from the response.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one more question regarding unique values of multiselect managed metadata column, could you check it please? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217821/multi-select-managed-metadata-column-get-distinct-values